# Django - Pass Data from View to Db to allow use in View

Tags: django, forms, post, redirect, django-forms

```
def Scan(request):
    form = SubmitDomain(request.POST or None) # A form bound to the POST data
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        if form.is_valid(): # If form input passes initial validation...
            domainNmCleaned = form.cleaned_data['domainNm']  ## clean data in dictionary
            form.save() #save cleaned data to the db from dictionary
            try:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/Processscan/?domainNm=' + domainNmCleaned)
            except:
                raise ValidationError(('Invalid request'), code='invalid')    ## [ TODO ]: add a custom error page here.
    else:
        form = SubmitDomain()

    return render(request, 'VA/index.html', {
        'form' : form
    })

def Processscan(request):
    EnteredDomain = request.get('domainNm', '')
    return HttpResponse("We got to the processor with domain: " + EnteredDomain)
```

Please go easy on me - I'm still learning :)

I'm having an issue now with GET, when im using POST, on my initial request for a domain name - I'm getting:

```
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'
```

on:

```
EnteredDomain = request.get('domainNm', '')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call scanprocess directly or simply just pass it by GET:

```
if form.is_valid(): # If form input passes initial validation...
    domainNm = form.cleaned_data['domainNm']  ## clean data in dictionary
    form.save() #save cleaned data to the db from dictionary

    try:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/Scanprocess/?domainNm=' + domainNm)
    except:
        raise ValidationError(_('Invalid domain name'), code='invalid')
```

Then in your view you can just get it through `request.GET.get('domainNm', '')`

And so far as I know all you need is in the `urls.py` is:

```
url(r'^Scanprocess/$', name_of_view),
```

Comment: Does this have security implications though?

Comment: Not that I know of. The user could send any GET string he wants regardless.

Comment: You should handle HttpResponseRedirect exceptions though.

Comment: Could you update your answer with a brief example? I would really appreciate it

Comment: Additionally, how can I then access the value of domainNm within the Scanprocess view ?

Comment: Your help with this will be incredibly helpful. Thank you

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you for explaining. One last thing - could you let me know what the issue is with my urlconf above? Do I explicitly have to define what the url parameter would look like e.g. ?domainNm=domain.com in urlconf? I know django is explicitly typed typically...

Comment: Want to go in a quick chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35008/discussion-between-codetalk-and-dan-klasson)

Comment: Im in the chat if you want to talk. The problem is my form is using POST, not GET, which is causing the error above. Can you please help?!

Comment: Disregard last few posts - I was able to figure it out. Thanks for your help!